# Prove that $f\in \mathcal{L}^1$ iff $\int|f|d\mu<\infty$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

One of the properties of Lebesgue integrable functions, as stated [here](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/lebesgue_integration.pdf) problem 3.7, is $f\in \mathcal{L}^1$ iff $\int|f|d\mu<\infty$ ,where $\mathcal{L}^1$ is the family of all integrable functions.

I tried proving this by:
$$f\in \mathcal{L}^1\implies \int f^+d\mu<\infty \text{ and } \int f^-d\mu<\infty$$
hence 
$$\int |f|d\mu=\int |f^+-f^-|d\mu$$

And here I don't know how can I break up the integral. on the other hand:
$$\int |f|d\mu<\infty\implies\int |f|d\mu=\int |f|^+d\mu-\int |f|^-d\mu=\int |f|^+d\mu=\int f^+d\mu<\infty$$
Is this any good?

How do I show both sides?

Comment: Generally the definition of $\mathcal{L}^1$ is $\int |f|<\infty$.

Comment: How do you prove a definition?

Comment: Ok, just note that $|f|=f^++f^-$.

Comment: is the second line any good?

Comment: You could make your question better by providing all the definitions of the key terms in your statement.

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathcal{L}^1$?

Comment: Then one might ask what is your definition of "Lebesgue integrable". Different textbooks would probably give different definitions. Without giving appropriate context, it would be difficult for others to answer your questions.

Comment: @Jack I have edited to include the source of my question as an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,
$$f \in \mathcal L^1 \quad \text{ iff } \quad \int f^+ d\mu < \infty \text{ and } \int f^- d\mu < \infty.$$
Now assume $f \in \mathcal L^1$. Since $|f| = f^+ + f^-$, we get
$$\int |f| d\mu = \int f^+ + f^- d\mu = \int f^+ d\mu + \int f^- d\mu$$
by linearity, and both of these are by definition $< \infty$, so $\int |f|d\mu < \infty$.

For the opposite direction, we will prove the contrapositive. Assume that $f \notin \mathcal L^1$. Again we get
$$\int|f|d\mu = \int f^+ d\mu + \int f^- d\mu,$$
but since $f \notin \mathcal L^1$, one of two summands on the right side must be $\infty$. Hence $\int |f|d\mu = \infty$.